# Insert only the date in timestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql

On my db under the time_ts columns, I have the date for example

2018-06-11 13:00:00

2018-06-12 17:00:00

2018-06-12 10:00:00

I use this query to insert in this column:

> INSERT INTO `tbl_score` (`Time_ts`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

From **time_ts** column, I want to get the date and insert into the **date_ts** column automatically after each insert.
Finally, I want to see this:

time_ts ..............   |    date_ts

.....................................................

2018-06-11 13:00:00 .......  2018-06-11

2018-06-12 17:00:00 .......  2018-06-12

2018-06-12 10:00:00 .......  2018-06-12

Excuse me, I have to edit my question...

now how do I Update rows?
I want to read from time_ts and update date_ts

Comment: This question is very confusing. What does your table look like? What are the columns and their types? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Are you asking for an insert, an update, or both?

Comment: I`m asking for update at this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_score (Time_ts,date_ts) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '%Y-%m-%d'));
```

Example [here](http://rextester.com/KCX38861)

Output is:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP      date
11.06.2018 11:50:34    2018-06-11
```

**EDIT:**

for `UPDATE` use this:

```
UPDATE tbl_score SET date_ts = (DATE_FORMAT(Time_ts, '%Y-%m-%d'));
```

Comment: Thanks, But how i can Update date_ts of old rows?

Comment: `UPDATE tbl_score  SET date_ts = (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,(DATE_FORMAT(Time_ts, '%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: its good but I have to get data from time_ts and convert it to date then insert into the date_ts.

Answer (score 2):

or maybe you can use `INSERT INTO tbl_score (Time_ts, Date_ts) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NOW());` instead.

Answer (score 2):

simply use date_format function,

```
INSERT INTO tbl_score (Time_ts,date_ts) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,(date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'%Y-%m-%d'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CURDATE()` if you want the current date (at midnight):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_score (time_ts, date_ts)
SELECT NOW(), CURDATE() FROM dual;
```

### Demo

I don't see much point in doing this, since the `date_ts` value can easily be generated from the `time_ts` value when you query.

Answer (score 1):

You need a trigger to achieve that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_aptbl_score 
  AFTER INSERT ON tbl_score 
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.date_ts  = DATE_FORMAT(time_ts , '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Just a small thing. I would prefer to use `AFTER INSERT` instead of `BEFORE INSERT`, because there is a possibility, when something goes wrong by inserting on `tbl_score` the insert `SET new.date_ts  = DATE_FORMAT(time_ts , '%Y-%m-%d')` will be already executed, what probably you don't want to. But it is a rare scenario.

Comment: That's a nice catch @AndreiSuvorkov.